# How to indexing multi-dimensional arrays given by indices in a certain axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing, numpy-indexing

Let's say I have a 4d array `A` with shape `(D0, D1, D2, D3)`. I have a 1d array `B` with shape `(D0,)`, which includes the indices I need at axis 2.

The trivial way to implement what I need:

```py
output_lis = []
for i in range(D0):
    output_lis.append(A[i, :, B[i], :])
#output = np.concatenate(output_lis, axis=0) #it is wrong to use concatenate. Thanks to @Mad Physicist. Instead, using stack.
output = np.stack(output_lis, axis=0) #shape: [D0, D1, D3]
```

So, my question is how to implement it with numpy API in a fast way?

Comment: The shape of your output is not as you say

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with broadcasting, and you should always include a tag for the library you are using. (Fixed for you)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! I have edited the problem. concatenate -> stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fancy indexing to step along two dimensions in lockstep. In this case, `arange` provides the sequence `i`, while `B` provides the sequence `B[i]`:

```
A[np.arange(D0), :, B, :]
```

The shape of this array is indeed `(D0, D1, D3)`, unlike the shape of your `for` loop result.

To get the same result from your example, use `stack` (which adds a new axis), rather than `concatenate` (which uses an existing axis):

```
output = np.stack(output_lis, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is entirely what I need and it is much more efficient! I edit the problem:concatenate -> stack.